# Converting integer to series of characters corresponding to digit of this integer

Tags: python, integer

I need a way to "convert" an integer into series of characters corresponding to digit specified by this integer. For example: if an integer equal 15 I want python to print me fifteen characters, can be spaces or whatever. How to do this? It would be nice if there is both an "manual way" and .method or function to do this.

Comment: This smells like a homework assignment. Sorry, I'm not going to help you get a good grade. Hint: Take a look at the string `ljust` and `rjust` methods. Or the string formatting DSL: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings. Or just use the multiply, `*`, operator to repeat a character the desired number times.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a string repetition operator (`*`) that does exactly this:

```
>>> print '.' * 15
...............
```

The above repeats the string `'.'` fifteen times.

Comment: @user9546355: You can use a variable instead of a constant.

Comment: What I want to do is that I need a dynamic number of spaces in each row so after loop is complete my numbers will be shifted to the right "side". I know that there is a method to do this but I need to do this by myself.